# MongoDB $group pipeline (in Mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongo collection that contains documents that look like this:

```
{
    "record" : "1",
    "site_id" : "abc1",
    "month" : "2013-12",
    "recorded" : ISODate("2013-12-18T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "status" : "OK",
    "comment" : "blah blah blah..."
}

{
    "record" : "2",
    "site_id" : "abc1",
    "month" : "2013-12",
    "recorded" : ISODate("2013-12-18T06:00:00.000Z"),
    "status" : "OK",
    "comment" : "blah blah blah..."
}

{
    "record" : "3",
    "site_id" : "abc2",
    "month" : "2013-12",
    "recorded" : ISODate("2013-12-18T06:00:00.000Z"),
    "status" : "OK",
    "comment" : "blah blah blah..."
}

{
    "record" : "4",
    "site_id" : "abc2",
    "month" : "2013-12",
    "recorded" : ISODate("2013-12-18T11:00:00.000Z"),
    "status" : "ERROR",
    "comment" : "something wrong"
}

{
    "record" : "5",
    "site_id" : "abc2",
    "month" : "2013-11",
    "recorded" : ISODate("2013-11-17T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "status" : "OK",
    "comment" : "blah blah blah..."
}
```

I want to use the $group operator to make a Mongoose call to return all values of the latest record (determined by the ISODate()) for a given month for each site_id.  So, for the month of 2013-12, I'd want to get back record 2 (the latest in 2013-12 for abc1) and record 4 (the latest in 2013-12 for abc2).

I can do it with a map/reduce function but I was wondering whether it is doable just with the Mongoose API and the aggregation framework (without calling a map/reduce function).  I feel like it should be but I haven't been able to make it work!

Comment: Could you edit the question to include some of the attempts you made and what didn't work? With the aggregation framework and the pipeline, it's best if you work step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of your documents have all the same fields present, you could use the Aggregation Framework to find the "last" record for each grouping of month and site.

NOTE: while the query below returns the expected results, it is not overly efficient or scalable so you should test with a representative data set.  The `$group` approach needs to sort much more data in the first step than you actually want to return.  An alternative approach would be to an run an aggregation per site using `$sort` and `$limit`.  MongoDB 2.4+ has [an optimization](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4656) for the Aggregation Framework use case of `$sort` followed by `$limit` (since the number of top-n results to keep is known), so multiple efficient queries could have a lower overall execution time than a single inefficient one.

Sample aggregation:

```
db.sites.aggregate(

    // Need to sort first so "last" makes sense in the $group
    { $sort: {
        month : 1,
        site_id: 1,
        recorded: 1,
    }},

    // Find the last monthly record for each site_id
    { $group: {
        _id: { "month" : "$month", site_id: "$site_id" },
        record: { $last: "$record" },
        site_id: { $last: "$site_id" },
        month: { $last: "$month" },
        recorded: { $last: "$recorded" },
        status: { $last: "$status" },
        comment: { $last: "$comment" }
    }}

)
```

Sample result:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : "2013-12",
                "site_id" : "abc2"
            },
            "record" : "4",
            "site_id" : "abc2",
            "month" : "2013-12",
            "recorded" : ISODate("2013-12-18T11:00:00Z"),
            "status" : "ERROR",
            "comment" : "something wrong"
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : "2013-12",
                "site_id" : "abc1"
            },
            "record" : "2",
            "site_id" : "abc1",
            "month" : "2013-12",
            "recorded" : ISODate("2013-12-18T06:00:00Z"),
            "status" : "OK",
            "comment" : "blah blah blah..."
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `aggregate` to get a particular element of each group, you need to include a `$sort` stage in your pipeline before the `$group` that puts the desired element first for each group so that you can use the `$first` operator to pick out the fields you want from the first doc in that group.

In the shell:

```js
db.test.aggregate(
    {$match: {month: '2013-12'}}, 
    {$sort: {recorded: -1}}, 
    {$group: {
        _id: '$site_id', 
        record: {$first: '$record'},
        recorded: {$first: '$recorded'},
        status: {$first: '$status'},
        comment: {$first: '$comment'}
    }})
```